# Deleted answer just says "deleted" but doesn't actually disappear

Tags: support, deleted-answers

Hi guys,

Yesterday, I answered an old SO question of mine with the workaround I eventually used.  I originally put this as an answer, but then realised it would be more appropriate as a comment on the question, as it's not really an answer at all.

So after adding the same info as a comment, I tried to delete this answer, but it just sits there with a red background saying "deleted".  I was wondering if it will ever actually be removed from the site?  Do I have to wait for it to timeout or something?  Or does a moderator have to get involved?

[How do I implement full text search in Chinese on PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3994504/how-do-i-implement-full-text-search-in-chinese-on-postgresql)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Deleted answers are still visible to their author, diamond moderators, and all normal users with 10,000 or more reputation points. That is very much by design. (I, for one, have only a couple rep points on StackOverflow, and I can confirm that your deleted answer is not displayed to me at all.)

Answer (score 5):

Because you are the author of that answer, it is visible to you.  It is also visible to 10k users and mods.  It is not visible to other users though, which is what the red background indicates.