# Deletions don't show up in the profile's activity tab

Tags: support, deleted-answers, self-delete, activity

I just deleted an answer of my own that should have been a comment. I would have expected a deletion action to show up in the activity tab of my profile, but there isn't.

What's the rationale to ignore deletions in the activity?

PS: I know now that I also could have flagged the answer for conversion into a comment, but it was an old and inactive question, so no need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No deleted content appears in user profiles, not even for 10k users. Only diamond mods can see those posts right in the profile. (Not saying this is necessarily the behaviour we'd like, but that's what happens.)

The reason why it's done this way is because deleted content is considered as "never having been created in the first place." This is also why a reputation recalc does not count reputation earned or lost on deleted content.

Comment: I see. It's never been created in some places, but in other it is? According to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72848/deleted-answer-just-says-deleted-but-doesnt-actually-disappear, it remains visible to me in the context of the question. And I noticed also that for some questions the last activity show in the overview is from a deleted answer. Should I file a bug for this?

Comment: @pesche: Correct, deleted answers are visible to you, and to 10k users in the context of a question. 10k users can also see entire deleted questions in the context of a question. However, no one except diamond mods can see deleted content in the context of a *user profile*. With regards to the last activity being from a deleted answer, this is by design.